# shared_timed_mutex not available on OS X 10.11.2?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, c++14

I'm trying to play around with the new `shared_timed_mutex` structures from C++ 14 on OS X 10.11.2 using Eclipse CDT 4.5.0. Xcode is 7.2. I'm using GCC C++ with the following options:

```
-O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++14
```

Her's what I get:

```
Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
g++  -o "MyProject" ./src/main.o  
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::shared_timed_mutex::shared_timed_mutex()", referenced from:
  HashMap<int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,         std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::hash<int> >::HashMap() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here's my clang version info:

```
 Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
 Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0
 Thread model: posix
```

I've searched my way through the web and found a couple of recommendations, for example this one on Reddit:

https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/3ejfkr/is_c14s_stdshared_timed_mutex_available_on_os_x/?

This is very close to my problem, I've tried the suggestions, but I´m hoping, that I won´t have to do the manual libc++ download, but could stick with the standard libs shipped with my system.

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure that you use clang or a recent gcc build from homebrew and not the standard gcc which maps to clang with a weird stdlib config.

Comment: You were right, downloading the latest gcc via homebrew did the job. I downloaded version 5 via `brew install gcc5`. After changing the tool settings in eclipse for compiler and linker to g++-5, my code compiled including `shared_timed_mutex`. Now there´s only one problem left. Eclipse  still does not find the symbols for `std::shared_timed_mutex`, even though I added the 5.2.0 include folder to the include paths of my project. Any ideas regarding that one? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

For the past two years (as I write this) Apple has updated the libc++ headers for their tools releases, but not the libc++ sources.  And libc++ implements `std::shared_time_mutex` both in `<shared_mutex>` and in shared_mutex.cpp.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apple dev presentation](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/405i2ilotov3bazyei1/405/405_whats_new_in_llvm.pdf) the `shared_timed_mutex` will be available starting with macOS 10.12. See page 52